# Android Properties not updating after editing and committing

Tags: android, preferenceactivity

in the onCreate method of my PreferenceActivity i set some Properties like this:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);      
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

editor.putBoolean("pref_mykey", true);

editor.commit();
```

It seems to work but the View is not updating so when i open the properties the onCreate runs and changes the values. I will then see the "old" values on the Screen until i close and reopen the prefs screen, then i do see the new properties.

I already tried this after the commit:

```
((BaseAdapter) getPreferenceScreen().getRootAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

But without any effect. I still see the "old" Prefs until i close and reopen the PreferenceActivity .

What am i doing wrong? How can i refresh the PreferenceActivity after setting values in the onCreate method?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This was buggin me all day but finally found a solution.

((ListPreference)getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("key_of_preference_in_xml_file")).setValue(code);

Your example is with a boolean so it'll have to change based on what kind of preference it is.
IE:
((CheckBoxPreference)getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("key_of_preference_in_xml_file")).setChecked(true);

Answer (score 0):

If you use a PreferenceFragment than you need to inject the PreferenceScreen in the activity.

```
public class SettingsActivity extends Activity implements ScanFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    private PreferenceScreen prefScreen;

    public void setPreferenceScreen(PreferenceScreen prefScreen){
        this.prefScreen = prefScreen;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(String scanContent) {
        // commiting to editor retrieved from preference manager would not refresh view
        EditTextPreference pref = (EditTextPreference)this.prefScreen.findPreference(getString(R.string.preference_url_key));
        pref.setText(scanContent);
    }

    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Load the preferences from an XML resource
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
            ((SettingsActivity)this.getActivity()).setPreferenceScreen(this.getPreferenceScreen());
        }
    }
}
```